# Hi, I want to create a second column in my dataframe with only specific values of the first column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with names of regions and their states:

```
    0   1
0   Alabama[edit]   Alabama[edit]
1   Auburn  Auburn
2   Florence    Florence
3   Jacksonville    Jacksonville
4   Livingston  Livingston
5   Montevallo  Montevallo
6   Troy    Troy
7   Tuscaloosa  Tuscaloosa
8   Tuskegee    Tuskegee
9   Alaska[edit]    Alaska[edit]
10  Fairbanks   Fairbanks
11  Arizona[edit]   Arizona[edit]
12  Flagstaff   Flagstaff
13  Tempe   Tempe
...
```

All the states has this [edit] at the end of their names.

I want the values of the second column to be only the name of the sates corresponding to that specific region.

Expected output:

```
    0   1
0   Alabama[edit]   Alabama[edit]
1   Auburn  Alabama[edit]
2   Florence    Alabama[edit]
3   Jacksonville    Alabama[edit]
4   Livingston  Alabama[edit]
5   Montevallo  Alabama[edit]
6   Troy    Alabama[edit]
7   Tuscaloosa  Alabama[edit]
8   Tuskegee    Alabama[edit]
9   Alaska[edit]    Alaska[edit]
10  Fairbanks   Alaska[edit]
11  Arizona[edit]   Arizona[edit]
12  Flagstaff   Arizona[edit]
13  Tempe   Arizona[edit]
...
```

How can I do this with pandas?

Comment: Please include the expected output as a dataframe. Your explanation is unclear.

Comment: I've edited  and aded the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the locations that do NOT have `"[edit]"` in them, and replace them with `nan`s:

```
df.loc[df[1].str.find('[edit]') == -1, 1] = np.nan
```

Forward-fill the `nan`s:

```
df[1].ffill(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, could you explain me what the -1 is for?

Comment: `find` returns -1 when it cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x : x.replace("[edit]", ""))
```

1 being the index of the second column

This takes far less time than the alternate solution mentioned.